# How to run an ".exe" file throw PHP class

Tags: php

how can i run an ".exe" file throw my PHP class?
Or is there any other way to do that?

I have already used

```
exec();
passthru();
```

function but its give me error, my code :

```
$path = "C:\Program Files\Softland\doPDF 7\dopdf.exe";

$result = passthru('$path 2>&1');
```

Error :

```
'$path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: This is super secure.

Comment: `Throw` or `through`?

Comment: Just convert single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a good practice but ....

```
$result = passthru($path.' 2>&1');
```

or

```
$result = passthru("$path 2>&1");
```

you should (as you can see) put `$path` variable outside single quotes (that prevent variable evaluation and substitution) or put double qoutes (that permits variable substitution)

Comment: Woot! Finally someone showed concatenation, I swear noone knows how to concatenate strings with variables these days...

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: evidently not all users can do that themselves :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quote if you want $path to be replaced by variable value so

```
$result = passthru("$path 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using single quotes, so the string passed to the shell was literally '$path 2>&1'. Variable substitution does not occur in side single quotes, only double, in PHP.

So you need to either concatenate the string or put it in double quotes.

$result =  passthru("$path 2>&1");